# What is the correct API to use to get a JSFiddle as JSON?

Tags: jsfiddle

It is clear from the following [page](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/post.html#) how to ***post*** a jsFiddle but it is not clear how to then ***get*** that same jsFiddle?